# How to purge data from tablea which is older than 200 days

Tags: sql, oracle, purge

I am new to database. i want to purge some data from table (i.e. purge old data which is older than 200 days) so for that I got one Sql script. Can some one help me how to run script  `@purge.sql "no of days"`

```
SQL>@@purge.sql 200
```

Actually my aim is to claim disk space server. After purge we need to perform any steps to claim file system.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PURGE_REC 
(
  DAYS IN VARCHAR2 /* Number of days as an parameter*/

) AS 
BEGIN
/* This deletes the records from the tables TRACK_DETAILS,LOG_DETAILS  tables of TEST schema*/

  DELETE FROM TRACK_DETAILS WHERE TO_CHAR(CREATION_TIME,'DD-MON-YY') < TO_DATE(SYSDATE -DAYS);
  DELETE FROM LOG_DETAILS WHERE TO_CHAR(CREATION_TIME,'DD-MON-YY') < TO_DATE(SYSDATE -DAYS);
  COMMIT;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The records are deleted successfully');

END TEST_PURGE_REC
```

Comment: This looks to be an Oracle procedure. Add an `oracle` tag to your question and remove the `sql-server` tag (Microsoft SQL Server).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change it mssql format as your query is in oracle standard

```
   DELETE FROM TRACK_DETAILS 
   WHERE convert(date,CREATION_TIME) < dateadd(day,-200,getdate());

    go

   DELETE FROM LOG_DETAILS
   WHERE convert(date,CREATION_TIME) < dateadd(day,-200,getdate());
```

Comment: Actually i want steps to run above sql script in linux. it is porvided by DB team but i am not aware DB script running from linux. I know prompt to SQL>@script.sql but i want here is how to provide DAYS along script

Comment: @SatyaVeera what dbms you used?